# How to implement a system call that could check if itself has been successfully executed without going to the kernel log?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, system-calls

I have just stepped into the kernel world and would like to add some system calls. My goal is to add a system call that lets me check if it executed (without looking at the kernel log). However, I have been thinking for a long time, but have not yet figured out how to implement it. Could anyone please give me some advice? Or some pseudocodes? Thanks in advance.

My thinking is that we could implement a new system call, in which it writes something into a buffer. Then, another system call reads the content of the buffer to check if the previous system call has written to the buffer. (Somehow like `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`) Hence, my implementation consists of 2 system calls in total.

Here is a sketch of my thinking written in pseudocode:

```
syscall_2(...){
    if (syscall_1 executes)
        return 0;
    if (syscall_1 NOT executes)
        return -1;
}

syscall_1(){
    do something;
    create a buffer;
    write something into buffer;
    
    return syscall_2(buffer); // checks what is in buffer
}
```

Comment: Why is it a problem to wait for the system call to complete? Like, what is it you're ultimately trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Also,it sounds like you may want to outline the actual problem you're trying to solve in the question.

Comment: My goal is to add a system call that lets me check if it executed (without looking at the kernel log). @Omnifarious

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I would edit the question. @oakad

Comment: System calls all return error codes. You can easily tell if a system call completed by examining the error code. Why do you need an alternate method to discover if a system call completed successfully? What are you trying to accomplish. What problem are you trying to solve that you think you need to do this in order to solve it?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, neither from the description nor from the pseudocode. "My goal is to add a system call that lets me check if it executed" - In other words, you want to implement a **function** `foo` in the Linux kernel, which checks whether `foo` is **currently executed**? This is always true. Or do you want to check whether `foo` has been **completed** at least once? If yes, then just define a boolean variable, which is set to true by `foo` at the end of its execution.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you have the system call itself accept a pointer to a userspace buffer that it overwrites with a specific piece of information.

You will have to learn how to access userspace memory, and more importantly how to verify that you were given a pointer to memory the process has mapped, and has write access to.

Then, once the system call completes, your program that called it can not only check the return code of the system call, you can also examine the memory to see if the system call wrote the correct thing to it.

Comment: Thanks! That's great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, system calls inform the caller if they are executed (how it went) so I guess you are interested in knowing which system calls have been executed, and how many times.

From this perspective, I think the best is to implement a device that can be queried (by means of some ioctl call) and let you know statistics about the individual system calls you can be interested on.

For example.... you can implement the number of system calls of type `n` you have used in some time.... by checking a counter at start time of interval and at end, and then check how many calls (if you implement a counter) you did in between by just subtracting the counter values at both times.  You can also do the same to e.g. calculate the average time, by accumulating the time a system call takes to execute at the end of it.  If you do this for example in picosecs, you can be sure this will be a good idea that you can publish.  In this schema you can also account for the amount of I/O that each system call does, by counting the amount of bytes transferred to/from usermode.... You could implement this as ioctls to some device and then you don't need to add a system call for it.